# How can I prevent AutoHotkey hotstrings after an underscore character?

Tags: autohotkey

If I was Bill Gates, I would use this AutoHotkey script to convert my initials into my full name:

```
::bg::Bill Gates
```

I would be happy that typing `Regards, bg` would actually print "Regards, Bill Gates", but I could still successfully type `hobgoblin` without having "hoBill Gatesoblin" appear. Nice!

Now, when revising an MS Word (of course!) document, I would probably still not like to use OneDrive, so I would create a copy of the document and suffix the filename with `_BG`. I would that to remain a short "_BG", and I would go crazy if that would always turn out to be converted into "_Bill Gates", because spaces in filenames are still something to avoid.

What could I do, except type awkward walkarounds such as `_B(arrowleft)(arrowright)G` or `_BG(arrowleft)(return)`?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I can find that is working is something like this. Downfall is you have to duplicate your hotstrings.

```
:?:_bg::_bg

::bg::Bill Gates
```